# How to use \chapter{} in article class?

Tags: chapters, article

I am aware that \chapter{} is not available in article class. However, for some reason, I still wish to use it. How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a good reason you can’t use the `report` class instead?

Comment: article class and report class are generated from the same source file and essentially the only difference is that report has chapter so while you could define \chapter in a report document just using report is equivalent

Comment: Can't you use \part instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own \chapter command and then use it as usual.
Example:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

%Add chapter functionality in article class
\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\newcounter{Chapcounter}
\newcommand\showmycounter{\addtocounter{Chapcounter}{1}\themycounter}
\newcommand{\chapter}[1] 
{ {\centering          
  \addtocounter{Chapcounter}{1} \Large \underline{\textbf{ \color{blue} Chapter \theChapcounter: ~#1}} }   
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ \color{blue} Chapter:~\theChapcounter~~ #1}    
}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=black}
%%%%

%opening
\title{The Title}
\author{Author1, Author2}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\chapter{Introduction}
    \section{Motivation and Background}
    \section{Literature Survey}
\chapter{Numerical Setup}
    \section{Problem Forumulation}
         \subsection{Subsection-title}
\chapter{Results and Discussion}
     \section{Results}
     \section{Comparision with Literature}
\chapter{Conclusions and Future Scope}
     \section{Conclusions}
     \section{Future Scope}
\end{document}
```

The output would look like this:

[image]

Comment: why not use `report` ? Your chapter heading definition seems stratnge you use `\centering` but in a group so the heading is not centred but justified with a word space to the left of the title