# Reset table/equation/figures counter to 1 after every new chapter (for chapter functionality manually added in article class) and then increment

Tags: tables, chapters, counters, article

In reference to a question asked by @Bhanuday Sharma on [How to use \chapter{} in article class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/604927/5001), I was able to add the chapter functionality in `article` class using his answer to his own question.

But now I am trying to count the equations/figures/tables for a given chapter so that I can number them accordingly, for example, for the third table in document that come first under chapter 3 should be numbered as 3.1 rather than 3.3. I tried to use

```
\counterwithin{table}{Chapcounter}
\renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{Chapcounter}.\arabic{table}}
```

Below wont work for article class:

```
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Your typesetting objectives aren't entirely clear. Why go through needless contortions when a perfectly functional alternative -- the `report` document class -- is available and ready to go?

Comment: Yes, thank you Mico!